# Allow ordering in list_display a property field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to setup ordering in django admin list_display, but I cannot make it to work. I have tried with using queryset annotations, but I have not found how to annotate it with a model property.

The code:
**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Nome Próprio')
    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date of birth")
    
    @property
    def age(self):
        born = self.dob
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['name', 'dob', 'age']

def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(age='age')
    return qs
```

This is my attempt so far, is there any easy fix? I am quite a novice on Django.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```py
@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'dob', 'age']
    
    def age(self, obj):
        born = self.dob
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day)
    age.admin_order_field = 'dob' # set the field that is used for ordering
    age.short_description = 'Age' # set the name of the column
```

More info on [Django's ModelAdmin.list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) documentation.

Comment: Thank you. It solves this part, but how can I make it order by what I use on the admin? dob and age are related in this case, but what if I have a property that provides the number of days until aniversary and I want to order by that?

Comment: As per de documentation, you would have to use a Query Expression (for example `full_name.admin_order_field = Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')`)

Comment: Well, I have read the docs and full_name depends on first_name and last_name. I mean when you have to order straight from the property values, such as days_till_birthday, which is computed by a function that returns an int. If i try to set a property as admin_order_field i get "Cannot resolve keyword 'age' into field".

Comment: No you can't use a property, but you can compute an age, or even the number of days until aniversary using Query Expression like `ExpressionWrapper(F('dob') - Now(), output_field=fields.DurationField())`